# How can I find out under what license a title was submitted to arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

How can I find out under what license a title was submitted to arXiv, and what conditions apply to sharing or redistribution?

Answer (score 2):

There is licence link under download.

Example here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.10781

And screen capture here:

[image: arxiv screen capture showing license link]

Comment: A reason to link the abstract page always, and not merely the PDF itself.

Answer (score 2):

Émile Bernard's answer shows you where to find the license.

The most common choice is [non-exclusive license to distribute](https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html).  This means only that arXiv.org has permission to distribute the paper.  **You**, as the downloader, do not get any such rights, so in this case you have no legal right to share or redistribute the paper at all.  (Unless your country's copyright laws give you some rights automatically, via "fair use" provisions or the like.)

Other papers have various forms of Creative Commons licenses, in which case the license will state explicitly under what conditions you may share or redistribute the paper.